# Json file not readable?

Tags: python, json

I'm very new to Python, so I apologize in advance for my stupid questions.

I'm trying to run  [this app](https://github.com/willdinkel/spotiminder)

This is the Python code:

```py
def load_json(path):
    with open(path, "r") as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        validate(instance=data, schema=schema)
        return data
```

I followed all the steps and think I did everything right, but once I run the app through terminal with required info (Client ID, client Secret and path to Json metadata), I get this error:

> "<C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\spotiminder-master\playlist.json> is not readable."

I tried to change the location of the JSON file and rename the file but neither worked.  What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: This looks like a problem with the permissions on the file or how you are running the code, not the code itself.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Does `path` include the angle brackets (i.e., `<` and `>`)?

Comment: @chepner I tried to look at the file permission but everything is ok :/

Comment: @DanielWalker The path itself does not include the angle brackets, but according to the instructions they're necessary to correctly run the program. However I also tried to delete the angle brackets but got the same error:  C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\spotiminder-master\spotiminder\playlist.json is not readable.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to find your file in `"<C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\spotiminder-master\playlist.json>"`

But i think, you're file is here: `"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\spotiminder-master\playlist.json"`
remove the `<>` of your path and it'll work

Comment: The path itself does not include the angle brackets, but according to the instructions they're necessary to correctly run the program. However I also tried to delete the angle brackets but got the same error: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\spotiminder-master\spotiminder\playlist.json is not readable.

Answer (score 0):

Watch what happens when I try to use the path for the file you used in an IPython session:

```
In [1]: path = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\spotiminder-master\playlist.json"
  File "<ipython-input-1-1980786d97e2>", line 1
    path = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\spotiminder-master\playlist.json"
                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

In Python string the `\U` has special meaning. It is the start of a Unicode escape sequence.

Try using the following filename (note the double backlash): `C:\\Users\Administrator\Desktop\spotiminder-master\playlist.json`

Comment: Much better: use a raw string, like `path = r”C:\….”` which doesn’t evaluate escape sequences.

Comment: @KirkStrauser The program gets the filename from the command-line.

Comment: @RolandSmith tried what you told and now it worked!! But unfortunately when it tries to open the Spotify authentication page we have a new error message saying: INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid client
 I checked If in the spotify for developers page I added the correct redirect URL and everything looks fine, don't know what's the issue now :/

Comment: @AriLeff I don't use spotify, so I can't help with that.